# storage error on default handler

Tags: java, xml, swing, parsing

I have to store data from sax parser in array but it shows nullreal values and lastly it is showing exception of Array out of bound. How do I add all the data types in array like name attribute vtype and value.

```
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;  
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes; 
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;

public class JTabbedPaneDemo extends JPanel {

     /*static String[] nameatt= {" sv_machineData "," Mould_data "," Core_1 "," Core_2 "};*/


    public JTabbedPaneDemo() {
    //  ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("java-swing-tutorial.JPG");

        JTabbedPane jtbExample = new JTabbedPane();

        // Create First Tab.
        JPanel jplInnerPanel1 = createInnerPanel();
        jtbExample.addTab(" Sv_Machine_Data ", jplInnerPanel1);
        jplInnerPanel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTable table1 = new JTable(5,3);
        JScrollPane tableContainer = new JScrollPane(table1);
        jplInnerPanel1.add(tableContainer,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //jtbExample.setSelectedIndex(0);

        // Create Second Tab.
        JPanel jplInnerPanel2 = createInnerPanel();
        jtbExample.addTab(" Mould_data ", jplInnerPanel2);
        jplInnerPanel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTable table2 = new JTable(5,3);
        JScrollPane tableContainer1 = new JScrollPane(table2);
        jplInnerPanel2.add(tableContainer1,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Create Third Tab.
        JPanel jplInnerPanel3 = createInnerPanel();
        jtbExample.addTab(" Core_1 ", jplInnerPanel3);
        jplInnerPanel3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTable table3 = new JTable(5,3);
        JScrollPane tableContainer3 = new JScrollPane(table3);
        jplInnerPanel3.add(tableContainer3,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Create Fourth Tab.
        JPanel jplInnerPanel4 = createInnerPanel();
        jtbExample.addTab(" Core_2 ", jplInnerPanel4);
        jplInnerPanel4.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTable table4 = new JTable(5,3);
        JScrollPane tableContainer4 = new JScrollPane(table4);
        jplInnerPanel4.add(tableContainer4,BorderLayout.CENTER);


        // Add the Tabbed Pane to this panel.
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        add(jtbExample);
    }


protected JPanel createInnerPanel() {
    JPanel jplPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel jlbDisplay = new JLabel();
    jlbDisplay.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    jplPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    jplPanel.add(jlbDisplay);
    return jplPanel;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String[] vt= {};
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TabbedPane Source Demo");
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    /*final JTabbedPaneDemo xm = new JTabbedPaneDemo();*/

    try {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

    DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

    boolean bfname = false;
    boolean blname = false;
    String nameAttribute;

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, Attributes attributes)
    throws SAXException {

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("TYP")) {
            bfname = true;
            }

        nameAttribute = attributes.getValue("Name");

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("VALUE")){
            blname = true;
            }
    }

    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
    throws SAXException {

        if (bfname) {
            System.out.println("Type : "+ new String(ch, start, length));
            String vtype = new String(ch, start, length);
            String [] typ = new String[length] ;
            for(int i=0;i<=length;i++) {
            typ[i]+=vtype;
            System.out.println("Type is "+typ[i]);
            }

            /*System.out.println("value of vt" +vt[j]);*/
            /*xm.textArea.append(vtype+"\n");*/
            bfname = false;
            }

        if (nameAttribute != null && !nameAttribute.equals("")) {
            //System.out.println("Name : " + nameAttribute);
            /*vname+=nameAttribute+ ", " +"\n";
            xm.textArea_3.setText(vname);
            */}

        if (blname) {   
            String vvalue = new String(ch, start, length);
            //System.out.println("Value:" + Double.valueOf(vvalue));
            /*xm.textArea_1.append(Double.valueOf(vvalue)+"\n");*/
            blname = false;
            }
    }
    };

    saxParser.parse(new File("my xmllocal address.xml"), handler);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JTabbedPaneDemo(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(400, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HMI_Data Version="1.0" MaschinenNR.="XXXXXX" Date="21-10-2009">
   <VarGroup Name="VG_MachineData">
      <Variable Name="Mold1.sv_rMoldStroke">
         <Typ>REAL</Typ>
         <Value>6.000000e+02</Value>
      </Variable>
      <Variable Name="Core1.sv_rMaxSpeedFwd">
         <Typ>REAL</Typ>
         <Value>5.000000e+01</Value>
      </Variable>
      <Variable Name="Core1.sv_rMaxSpeedBwd">
         <Typ>REAL</Typ>
         <Value>5.000000e+01</Value>
      </Variable>
      <Variable Name="Core1.sv_rMaxPressureFwd">
         <Typ>REAL</Typ>
         <Value>1.450000e+02</Value>
      </Variable>
      <Variable Name="Core1.sv_rMaxPressureBwd">
         <Typ>REAL</Typ>
         <Value>1.450000e+02</Value>
```

Comment: no idea, for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnale, compilable,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
 for(int i=0;i<=length;i++) {
     typ[i]+=vtype;
     System.out.println("Type is "+typ[i]);
 }
```

You're getting `null` at the start of each value because `typ[i]` is null before the concatenation.

You're getting an exception because you're using `<=` instead of `<` so on the last iteration, `i` will equal `length`, and `typ[i]` will therefore be invalid.

You *could* just fix the loop with:

```
 for (int i = 0;i < length; i++) {
     typ[i] = vtype;
     System.out.println("Type is " + typ[i]);
 }
```

... but it seems pretty pointless. I see no reason to create a string array in the first place.

If you need all the types in an array, you need to create that array (or ideally a list) *outside* the `characters` method... the `characters` method is called for each piece of text. You'd need to create the list as on-going state, and just *add* to it within the `characters` method.

Unless this is really a huge file, I would personally move away from SAX to start with - while it's very powerful for read-once huge files, it's a pain to work with compared with loading the whole file into some sort of DOM representation (potentially a 3rd party XML library such as JDOM).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually i have to appends all the nameAttributes to tabbedpane and type and value in table within so that is why i am trying this method.  If you have any better suggestion than do let me know.  Actually this is my trial to display parsed xml into tabbed pane with parent nodes on tab and child nodes in table.  the second portion includes editing xml file and output that again

Comment: Actually sir you are right on your part but i have to do every piece of work myself and no one to guide so till the time i dont face problem i wont be able to know.  over and above i am newbie on java.

Comment: As I say, my recommendation would be not to use SAX. I would strongly advise you to separate out your UI from your XML parsing part though - you should be able to test the XML part from either unit tests or a simple console app, long before you put it in a UI.#

Comment: Sir actually i have build a parser which would parse xml and display it in GUI and after certain editing tags displayed in GUI it would output xml again in end. Guide me if i am on wrong track.Thank you for your time and Assistance.